# Is there a possible way to override setActivated method?

Tags: android

guys, need help.
Is there a way to override setActivated() method to change the appearance of buttons that are activated?
Question may seem stupid but i am newbee in android, so thx for understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a selector. It basically defines a list of states and what to do when an View is in a such state. It behaves very much the same way as `if() else if() else if()`

Here is a sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/activated" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default" />
</selector>
```

You will find a longer explanation [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)